# Is there a way to shorten this loop into one line?

Tags: python

anyway to make this one line, but without list comprehension?

```
for x in someDict["place"]:  # make this
    for thing in x:          # and this one line?
        print(x[thing]["this_des1"])
        print(x[thing]["that_des2"])
```

```
someDict = {
"place": [ { 0 : { "this_des1": 'data1', "that_des2" : 'data2' } },
           { 1 : { "this_ces1": 'data3', "that_ces2" : 'data4' } } ] }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: is this site only for professional developers?

Comment: No, but it's not clear what your goal is. You should also stop using Python 2, it's no longer supported.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The code you posted raises a `KeyError` since the two `thing`s don't have the same keys.

Comment: @lip no, but it's also **not** an open forum. We have rules and norms around what content is acceptable and how it should be structured, which is why I linked you the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dicts have different keys, and it seems like you're trying to print all of the bottom-level values, it'd be easier to use `values()` rather than hardcoding the keys.

```
>>> print('\n'.join(z for x in someDict["place"] for y in x.values() for z in y.values()))
data1
data2
data3
data4
```